# Set activerecord attribute to boolean from string before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm parsing a CSV file and have a string column that should be boolean.
The values are either 'Y' or 'N'. I would like to process these in a callback and inserted as boolean. Is this possible with activerecord callbacks?

```
Rails 5.0.0
```

csv:

```
RULE_TYPE,DESCRIPTION,STANDARD_OPTION
OY,One,Y
TN,Two,N
```

migration:

```
...
  t.boolean :standard_option
...
```

model:

```
class OptionRule < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :standard_option_bool
  private
  def standard_option_bool
    puts self.standard_option
    self.standard_option=="Y" ? self.standard_option=true : self.standard_option=false
  end
end
```

rails c

```
2.3.1 :001 > OptionRule.create(rule_type:'OY', description:"One", standard_option: 'Y')
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
true
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "option_rules" ("rule_type", "description", "standard_option", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "rule_type"  [["rule_type", "OY"], ["description", "One"], ["standard_option", false], ["created_at", 2016-07-25 10:34:06 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-25 10:34:06 UTC]]
 (6.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<OptionRule rule_type: "OY", description: "One", standard_option: false, created_at: "2016-07-25 10:34:06", updated_at: "2016-07-25 10:34:06">
```

Notice that it returns 'true' for the puts command and not 'Y'. I have to think that activerecord is transforming this before callbacks.

Comment: Can you post the code where parsing it?  It would be better there.

Comment: what is wrong with what you wrote ? Is there any problems with your code ? It seems right to me at first glance.

Comment: That's verbatim what I have. Still inserts as false when standard_option: 'Y'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Even this will work

```
class OptionRule < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :standard_option_bool

  private

  def standard_option_bool
    self.standard_option = standard_option == "Y"
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks right but doesn't seem to work - Inserts as false w/ standard_option: 'Y'
        puts self.standard_option
returns true before inserting. Is it possible activerecord is converting the type before it touches my model?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing **1(true)** and **0(false)** for the boolean columns.

```
class OptionRule < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :standard_option_bool

  private
  def standard_option_bool
    self.standard_option=="Y" ? self.standard_option = 1 : self.standard_option = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Notice that it returns 'true' for the puts command and not 'Y'. I have to think that activerecord is transforming this before callbacks.

Comment: if you changed the column from string to boolean, it will return true itself

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
class OptionRule < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :standard_option_bool

  private

  def standard_option_bool
    self.standard_option = self.standard_option == "Y" ? true : false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by creating a temporary variable.

```
class OptionRule < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :standard_option_temp
  before_save :standard_option_bool
  private

  def standard_option_bool
    #puts self.standard_option_temp
    self.standard_option = standard_option_temp == "Y"
  end
end
```

Then just set OptionRule.standard_option_temp and let the validation set the boolean value